# Unable to connect to Apple server for Push Notification

Tags: ios, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, network-programming, afnetworking

Now i am connecting to apple server to generate push notification. but when i try to connect to apple server using tcpclient it generate an exception of unable to connect and i also ping the server using cmd ping and telnet command and i found that it not allow to communication. 
this is my code snippet

```
private void Connect(string host, int port, X509CertificateCollection     certificates)
        {
            Logger.Info("Connecting to apple server.");
            try
            {
                _apnsClient = new TcpClient(host, port);
               // _apnsClient.Connect(host, port);
            }
            catch (SocketException ex)
            {
                Logger.Error("An error occurred while connecting to APNS servers - " + ex.Message);
            }

            var sslOpened = OpenSslStream(host, certificates);

            if (sslOpened)
            {
                _conected = true;
                Logger.Info("Conected.");
            }

        }
```

this is the host "gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com" i also try the producation host but same exception occured. and using Port "2195" 
it generate the following Exception :
"A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 17.172.232.46:2195"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix this issue changing the X509Certificate to X509Certificate2 and also its Collection to X509Certificate2Collection and allow the setting from firewall.